# How to join two tables based on two columns and verifying that one column is existing in both

Tags: mysql, left-join

I have a table A and a table B. The tables can be joined based on the columns (say x and y in both).

I want to join both tables based on x and y to find out all rows in table A where the couple (x,y) doesn't exist in the table B.

What I do now is:

```
SELECT * FROM A a
LEFT JOIN B b
ON a.x = b.x AND a.y = B.y
WHERE b.x IS NULL AND b.y IS NULL;
```

And the result is ok...

But me I want to have couples (x,y) in A that don't exist in B and be sure only for couple where x exist in B...

Any idea?

I have the idea to do the following:

```
SELECT * FROM A a
LEFT JOIN B b
ON a.x = b.x AND a.y = B.y
WHERE b.x IS NULL AND b.y IS NULL
AND x in (SELECT x FROM B);
```

And that works but it seems for me not a good way...

Sample data would be:

in A, we have (x,y):
(1,2)
(1,5)
(2,3)
(3,7)

in B, we have (x,y):
(1,4)
(1,5)
(3,9)

expected result is:

(1,2)
(3,7)

Comment: Can you post some sample data and expected result.  [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my experience, subqueries outside of the `FROM` clause have generally poor performance, this would probably be faster:

```
SELECT * 
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT x FROM B) AS bsAs
INNER JOIN A AS a ON bsAs.x = A.x
LEFT JOIN B AS b ON a.x = b.x AND a.y = B.y
WHERE b.x IS NULL AND b.y IS NULL
;
```

Edit: Don't forget the `DISTINCT` in the subquery, otherwise you'll get your results for each x value duplicated for every instance of that x value in B.

Comment: Yes that's why I said I know it's not the better way because I guess it decreases performance

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT A.*
FROM A
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM B
                  WHERE B.x = A.x 
                    AND B.y = A.y)
  AND EXISTS     (SELECT 1
                  FROM B
                  WHERE B.x = A.x)
```

This return all rows from A, where

- B doesnt have `A(x,y)`
- B have `A(x)`